# Thresholds for Bhattacharyya coefficient - when do the distributions differ significantly

Tags: statistical-significance, threshold, bhattacharyya

The Bhattacharyya coefficient of two discrete probability distributions is defined as
$$
BC(p,q) = \sum_{i=1}^n \sqrt{p_iq_i}.
$$
This coefficient lies within the interval $[0,1]$ and if $p=q$ then it is 1 as
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n \sqrt{p_i^2} = \sum_{i=1}^n p_i = 1.
$$
Thus values lower than 1 might indicate that $p$ and $q$ differ. Are there any thresholds derived in the literature or significance tests that give guidance when we can accept the hypothesis that $p$ and $q$ differ?

Comment: Do you mean statistical significance (p-value) or practical significance (big enough difference to interest an investigator)?

Comment: I am mainly interested in something statistically rigorous (like p-value). Besides this I would be interested in practical aspects too. Thank you @Dave

Comment: why wouldn't you use chi square or g test?

Comment: @carlo of course these tests would be a choice too. But I am rather in a discussion about this specific measure.

Comment: this specific measure has no consistent asymptotic distribution, so you can't use for hypothesis testing, unless you derive its distribution under the one-population hypothesis using bootstrap methods

Comment: @carlo could you please give some reference to statement about the consistent asymptotic distribution and to the approach "under the one-population hypothesis using bootstrap methods". If you could write this as answer I would most probably accept it. Thank you!

Comment: Are these distributions generated/sampled, or are they fixed? If they are fixed, having a test is non-sequitur: you already know they are, in fact, different.

Comment: @Fireburg the two distributions are sampled ... Thank you!